# JQuery required fields not stopping Ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to submit a form using Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#SubmitTicket").submit(function(e){
                CheckRequired();
                e.preventDefault();
                dataString=$("#SubmitTicket").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "?SubmitTicket=1",
                    cache: false,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(res) {
                        if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) {
                            //window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                            $("#CreateNewTicket_Body").html(res);
                            $("#CreateTicket").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

This function checks for `required` classes in form elements

```
function CheckRequired(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    var emptyElements = $form.find('.required').filter(function() {
        return this.value === ''
    });

    if(emptyElements.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();

        emptyElements.addClass("EmptySelect").attr('title', 'This field is required');

        //alert(emptyElements.attr("id"));
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");

        return false;
    }
}
```

I then have this code which automatically checks all my forms for required fields using the above function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', CheckRequired);
});
```

It works fine on forms that POST to another page.

When using the Ajax submit code, its display the `alert` when there is an error, but its still submitting the form.

Comment: On which browser are you testing it? Firefox?

Comment: Can you provide MCVE replicating issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to enclose the return of CheckRequired into an if() structure :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#SubmitTicket").submit(function(e){
                if(CheckRequired.call(this,e)) { // this should refer to the event target element, i.e. the form element, providing context for the function
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dataString=$("#SubmitTicket").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "?SubmitTicket=1",
                        cache: false,
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(res) {
                            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) {
                                //window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                                $("#CreateNewTicket_Body").html(res);
                                $("#CreateTicket").hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: should it not be if(!CheckRequired)  ?

Comment: I don't think so, because CheckRequired is built as an event handler and its boolean return value here means "shall we go on with the event processing ? (yes/no)". To be on the safe side, you also might want to make it return true for the default case at the end of the function.

Comment: ok, im still seeing the error which is correct but its still submitting the form

Comment: do i not need to use if(CheckRequired("#form_id")) { ... }

Comment: my bad, you're right, actually it expects the event as an argument - updating my answer acordingly.

Comment: ok, i changed my code to if(CheckRequired(e)) { alert("YES"); } else { alert("NO"); } and everytime its returning the YES alert whether there are errors or not

Comment: my bad again - CheckRequired() expects the form element as context, which explains it does not work as expectd, updating the call in my answer.

Comment: ok working great now - only thing now is because the bit of JQuery is checking every single form in the whole site, and then i am checking again its showing the alert error in the function twice

Comment: granted, this function really shouldn't be called twice - guess you now only have to figure out which call is to be removed :) (my pick would be to remove this one first and see what happens)

Comment: @Camlimero im not sure what you mean in your last comment?

Comment: as you reported, CheckRequired() -_now working correctly_- is now called twice when you try to submit the form, meaning one of the two calls has to be removed. I'd suggest removing this one since the other one is generic and applies to all form elements.

Comment: but if i remove this one, its not going to work on my ajax form submit?

Comment: or do i change the code in my form checks ($('form').on('submit', CheckRequired);) to be your above code?

Comment: @charlie, the event handlers are all executed for a given event, they do not replace each other, what matters is their order of execution. I suppose the `$('form').on('submit', CheckRequired);` comes first in order so there is no need to call `CheckRequired` again in this other code block, as opposed to what we were trying to do until now. Why not give it a try ?

Comment: but what i had originally was the $('form').on('submit', CheckRequired); which checks every form, but even with that it was still submitting the ajax post form even though there are errors

Comment: ok ive reverted back to the original code which is working fine now and doing as its supposed to. however, the code inside if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) { is not completing. its not hiding the elements as the code says

Comment: even though there is a return false; in the CheckRequired function its not returning false because its still submitting the form

Comment: ok, let's forget that last advice and get back to where we were before when you saw the alert() twice. You can add `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` inside `CheckRequired()` just before the `return false;` to avoid the handler being executed twice in case some required fields are missing. It should work.

Comment: Ok I will give that a go tomorrow, so just put that in my function and leave my Ajax post request as it was originally?

Comment: almost, you have to get back to the code given in my answer and add that last line to the `CheckRequired()̀` function. Should be ok, waiting to hear from ya.

Comment: Ok so still use the if statement at the top of the Ajax form submit?

Comment: Yeah. fingers crossed :D

Comment: ok, that seems to have fixed it, but 'if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) {' isn't working on the ajax post success

Comment: you need to examine what's returned by the ajax query in your dev tools then

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add onSubmit="return CheckRequired()" in your form.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'CheckRequired()' return false, you need to stop the script by returning false.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#SubmitTicket").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!CheckRequired(e)) {
                   return false;
            }
            dataString=$("#SubmitTicket").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "?SubmitTicket=1",
                cache: false,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(res) {
                    if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) {
                        //window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                        $("#CreateNewTicket_Body").html(res);
                        $("#CreateTicket").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: won't work, as seen below CheckRequired() expects the form element as context to do its thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't see that, in this case the form element can be pass CheckRequired($(this).closest('form')), or you can get the form from event (e.target or e.currentTarget)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to approach this:

A) **Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SubmitTicket").submit(function(e){
        if(!CheckRequired()) return false; // THIS!
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString=$("#SubmitTicket").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?SubmitTicket=1",
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(res) {
                if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1) {
                    //window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                    $("#CreateNewTicket_Body").html(res);
                    $("#CreateTicket").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

B) **HTML**:

```
<form id="SubmitTicket" onSubmit="return CheckRequired();">
```

Comment: that would mean i need to go through and also change the code across my whole site (alot of forms (: )